# Converting Cifar10 dataset to RecordIO format for Amazon SageMaker

Tags: image-processing, amazon-sagemaker

I have downloaded cifar-10 dataset and need to convert it to `RecordIO` format. If you unzip the downloaded `cifar-10-python.tar.gz` dataset, you will see below

```
cifar-10-batches-py/
cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_4
cifar-10-batches-py/readme.html
cifar-10-batches-py/test_batch
cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_3
cifar-10-batches-py/batches.meta
cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_2
cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_5
cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_1
```

Now, I want to separate out the `data_batch_*.bin` to train set and `test_batch.bin` to test set and convert to `recordIO` format.

Following this tutorial [link](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/example/image-classification) but not sure how `im2rec`  actually works to make it happen.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use im2rec: https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/master/faq/recordio.html

Or you could download CIFAR-10 in RecordIO format directly:

```
wget http://data.mxnet.io/data/cifar10/cifar10_val.rec
wget http://data.mxnet.io/data/cifar10/cifar10_train.rec
```